# cannot cast from view to edittext

Tags: android-edittext

using this xml code

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:hint="Type Password"

android:password="True"
/>
```

and using this code

EditText edittext1 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1) ;

Comment: Please post ur xml and also the way you doing it in the onCreate , and also the log, then only could anyone really help

Answer (score 0):

hello m using this simple xml as m beginner

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"    

android:layout_height="match_parent"    

android:orientation="vertical" >    

<EditText    

    android:id="@+id/et1"    

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  

    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

    android:ems="10"    

    android:hint="Type Password"    

    android:password="True" >    

</EditText>    

<Button    

    android:id="@+id/bpass"    

    android:layout_width="match_parent" 

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   

    android:text="Password" />    

<ToggleButton    

    android:id="@+id/btogg"    

    android:layout_width="match_parent"    

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    

    android:text="ToggleButton"     

    android:onClick="True"    

    android:checked="True"/>
```

```
android:id="@+id/tv1"    

android:layout_width="match_parent"    

android:layout_height="wrap_content"    

android:text="TextView"     

android:textSize="30dp"    

android:layout_gravity="center"    

android:gravity="center"/>
```

this is code where m initializing the edit text

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class EditText extends Activity{

```
private static final EditText EditText = null;

Button pass;

ToggleButton toggle;

EditText edit;


TextView tv1;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.edittext);


    pass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bpass);

    toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btogg);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);


}
```

}